# System.Diagnostics.Meters in a library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, system.diagnostics

This is .NET 6 application on macOS 12.

I have a a library that contains a **System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource** that contains a set of **IncrementingEventCounters**. I can reference this library in a standalone console application or in an ASP.NET application and I can observe the counters using **dotnet-counters** with no issues.

I have replaced this **EventSource** with a **System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Meter** and a set of **System.Diagnostic.Metrics.Counters**. As with the previous **EventSource** implementation I can reference this library in a console application and observe the counters using **dotnet-counters** with no issues.

However, if I reference this Metrics implementation in an ASP.NET application I cannot observe the counters. **dotnet-counters** just sits and waits.

```
Press p to pause, r to resume, q to quit.
    Status: Waiting for initial payload...
```

If I add a **Meter** and **Counter** to the ASP.NET application Program.cs directly I can observe the counter as expected.

Is there some configuration or change required in the ASP.NET application to enable the publishing of Metrics from a library? Without seeing the code does this sound like I'm doing something wrong? Or does this look like a bug in the framework?

Comment: Are you calling the library? I wonder if it's lazy so first use of the counter will cause it to emit from the runtime.

Comment: I'm able to listen counter events if they are defined in a library and used in as.net core. Can you share your code, how you define and use counters? What are parameters for dotnet-counters?